# Are there any Android devices that cannot be rooted?

Tags: rooting

I bought a new Galaxy Mega and it seems nobody has figured out a root method for it yet.  Are there devices that have been on the market for more than a few months that are not rootable?

Comment: To my knowledge, all devices are rootable but if it is not a popular phone or it is a new phone, there might not be a kit for it yet

Comment: All android devices can be rooted. From what I've observed, there aren't many guides to root dual sim phones .

Comment: Just for clarification: Are you looking for a list of devices that have no rooting tools yet – or is your question rather *How do I root the Galaxy Mega?* In the latter case, you might wish to consult our [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) and [rooting device index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575). The latter also lists some "generic tools" you might want to try if there's no specific "rooting set" available for your device yet. Don't forget to report any success, you might even answer your own question :)

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia provides a few answers:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_rooting

> In the past, many manufacturers have tried to make "unrootable" phones
>   with harsher protections (like the Droid X), but they're usually still
>   rootable in some way, shape, or form. There may be no root exploit
>   available for new or recently updated phones, but one is usually
>   available within a few months.

But that's the past.

> Only a minority of Android devices lock their bootloaders—and many
>   vendors such as HTC, Sony, Asus and Google explicitly provide the
>   ability to unlock devices, and even replace the operating system
>   entirely.

So shortly speaking, no worries, if there's no root yet, surely there's one to come out soon.